# Txt file to 2D array

Tags: java

I am supposed to convert my 2nd line from my .txt file filled with 15 X's and O's and print it out onto a 2D array in java.

Here is my 1D array on my .txt file.

```
XOXOX
XOOXX
XXXOO
XXOOO
XXXXO
OOOOX
XOOXX
OOXXO
OXOXO
OXXXO
```

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the input filename ");
    String inputFile = in.next();
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File(inputFile));
    String line=inFile.nextLine();
    line.toUpperCase();
    String array[] = line.split("X");
    System.out.println(array[0]+  " " + array [1]);
    String arrayE1 = array[0];
    String arrayE2 = array[1];
    Integer.parseInt(arrayE1);
    Integer.parseInt(arrayE2);
    String line2 = inFile.next();
    System.out.println(line2);

    char [][] MovieTheater = new char [Integer.parseInt(arrayE1)][Integer.parseInt(arrayE2)];

    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < Integer.parseInt(arrayE1); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; i < Integer.parseInt(arrayE2); j++) {
            MovieTheater[i][j] = line2.charAt(k++);
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
    inFile.close();
}
```

Comment: So, what is your needs?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Files.lines()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-) to read all lines in the file and [`String.toCharArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray--) to get all the chars from each line:

```
try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(inputFile))) {
    char[][] movieTheater = lines
            .map(String::toCharArray)
            .toArray(char[][]::new);
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(movieTheater));
}
```

The result will be this 2D array:

```
[
    [X, O, X, O, X], [X, O, O, X, X], 
    [X, X, X, O, O], [X, X, O, O, O], 
    [X, X, X, X, O], [O, O, O, O, X], 
    [X, O, O, X, X], [O, O, X, X, O], 
    [O, X, O, X, O], [O, X, X, X, O]
]
```